# How to add text on dropdownmenu?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm making an app using Flutter and I want to add text for my `DropDownMenu` like `Select car make` or something like that.
I could not find a tutorial so was hoping someone could help.

Here is my code:

```
 new FormField(builder: (FormFieldState state) {
    
                        return InputDecorator(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            
    
                         ),
    
                          child:FutureBuilder<Album>(
                              future: futureAlbum,
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                  final album = snapshot.data;
                                  final results = album.results;
                                  return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
    
    
    
                                      child:  DropdownButton<Results>(
                                        
    
                                        isExpanded: true,
                                      items: results.map((result) {
                                        return DropdownMenuItem<Results>(
                                          value: result,
    
    
                                          child: Text('${result.modelName}'),
                                        );
                                      }).toList(),
                                      onChanged: (album  ) {
                                        // selected album
                                        setState(() {
                                          _selected = album;
    
                                        });
    
                                      },
                                        value: _selected,
                                      ));
                                } else
                                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                              }),
    
    
                        );
                      }),
```

I tried to set `hinttext`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can add a hint to your DropdownButton:

```
hint: Container(
  width: 150,
  child: Text(
    "Select car",
     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
     textAlign: TextAlign.end,
  ),
),
```